# VS Code custom color theme identifies, but does not render selected token color

Tags: visual-studio-code, color-scheme, rust-analyzer

I am using [TextMate](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars) rules to try and write a custom VSC Rust color theme that's not quite as busy as the default one, following [this explanation in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#semantic-theming).

For a token without semantic information, the VSC scope inspector correctly reports the color I selected (`#FF0000` in the screenshot), but does not render it. Am I misunderstandings how this feature works?

[image]

My minimal `settings.json` snippet looks like this:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Dark+]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "punctuation.brackets.curly.rust",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#FF0000"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false
```

VSC v1.71.2, rust-analyzer v0.3.1221

Comment: disable the default **bracket pair colorizer**, the `{` near the `if` is blue

Comment: This was the correct answer.